# Android NullPointerException on variable in instantiated class

Tags: java, android-listview, constructor, global-variables, scope

I have an activity that calls an expandablelistview.  It is a very vanilla setup:

Activity->creates the expandablelistviewadapter->draw it.

When the getChildView is called and it tries to reference a variable that was set via the listadapter's constructor it receives an NPE.

So ActivityA->data properly gets set, then is sent to the ArbitraryListAdapter.  When the childView method is referenced and tries to use dataFromActivityA I get a NullPointerException.  I'm really not sure why, when I verify dataFromActivityA in the adapter class, it verifies correctly.  Then when I try to reference it in the getChildView method the NPE shows up.

To explain with an example:

```
class ActivityA extends Activity {

    private SparseArray<SparseArray<Object>> data;
    private ArbitraryListAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate() {
        this.data = arbitraryFunctionToPopulateDataVariable(); // this properly populates
        this.adapter = new ArbitraryListAdapter(this, this.data);
        // do some other stuff

        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
// do the rest of the activity here
}
/******************************/
class ArbitraryListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private SparseArray<SparseArray<Object>> dataFromActivityA;

    public ArbitraryListAdapter(Context context, SparseArray<SparseArray<Object>> x) {
        this.dataFromActivityA = x; // at this point the variable is set properly
    }

    public View getChildView(int group, int child, boolean last, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Do some stuff
        // This is where the NPE arises!!!
        for(int i = 0;i< this.dataFromActivityA.size();i++){
            Log.d(TAG, "Group: " + i);
            for(int j = 0; j<this.dataFromActivityA.get(i).size();j++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Child: " + this.dataFromActivityA.get(j).toString());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "============================");
        }
    // Do some other stuff
    }
// Finish listadapter functions here
}
```

Comment: Why was this down voted with no comment?  I don't see how this question warrants a down vote.  It is neither egregiously sloppy or a no-effort-post (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).  I legitimately do not understand, under the context of knowing how variable scope, global variables and object construction why this is giving me an NPE.  I created a much simpler example of the actual code I'm using to make it easier and clearer as to where the problem arises.

I would at least liked a comment describing why this was worthy of a down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sigh* I am the worlds worst developer.  I didn't see that in my onResume() of the activity I was clearing the list.  How stupid am I!?